# IMG displaying in IE and not in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, image

I have an HTML document type which is designed to display a form pulling data from a database application and generating a webpage that can then be printed. It's not intended to be published online, I'm just using HTML & CSS to format the page as the reporting tools within the application don't allow for decent formatting.

I'm trying to display pictures which are held on a shared drive. The code used is

```
<IMG SRC="X:\images\<primarykey>.jpg" height="100">
```

where X is the drive on which the pictures live (which users have access to), and  is the unique identifier for each picture populated by the reporting tool when the html is generated.

IE can display the pictures, but Firefox does not and displays the  text instead. I really need to make this work in Firefox as IE is messing up the layout of the form further down.

I've experimented with changing the IMG SRC declaration, using a relative path and forward slashes, etc. but haven't been able to get it to work.

Any advice would be great!

Thanks
Kat

Comment: Do your img and src in lower case please ;)

Comment: I think the lowercase, while a good point (for markup cleanliness) is unlikely to cause these kinds of problems in modern browsers (even IE!)... Older HTML Doctypes used to require uppercase tags and elements.

Still a valid point though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions:

1. At mentioned by Sam, lower case the element and attributes.
2. Try src as: `src="file:///X:/images/.jpg"`
3. If the output is expected to be valid XHTML, you might need to ensure the  is self closing, eg:`<img .... />`